PC won’t power on fully or at all anymore
This started randomly about a year ago. It used to turn on and off for a bit, just enough for lights and fans to turn on then it turns off. It would do that, then start.  Now, it just does that once, won’t work then I have to leave it for hours where it will randomly work again later. Sleep mode used to work but now it doesn’t even stay powered sleeping anymore and repeats problem. I tried a brand new PSU, no effect. Reset cmos, reseated everything, one stick of ram rotated through each slot, unplugging all peripherals, making sure only certain parts plugged in. I’m completely lost, as when it turns on finally it works fine.

PSU was my initial thought too, so good job on already trying that. Have you tested that new PSU with a different system to ensure that the new PSU is not faulty too?

I haven’t. I’m going to later or tomorrow at a friends. I also have some cheap ram coming in to see if that’s it. Though, both my sticks are read when pc does work. It’s so weird, it won’t turn on then hours later i try and it does. Pretty much every time

Have you tried a different mains lead for the PSU? A different mains socket? Giving it a new CMOS battery?

Just ordered a new battery. Can you elaborate on “mains lead”? It’s a non modular PSU so I have just the 24 pin.

Well, I got the new mobo and cpu combo, added my PSU and gpu and ram I think came with it but I’ve had this combo for like two years before it randomly started about a year ago. Nothing was touched at all when it started.

It was fine, then about a year ago it started. At first it would happen like once every few months. I thought nothing of it because I read that humidity could cause this issue and I live kind of in the south between work. But now it’s so bad it’s every day. I can ever restart it and it will work but turning it off it won’t come back on

@JahnOssim Perhaps you know a mains lead as a power cord? The cord that you plug into the back of the PSU and the outlet on the wall.
